# VLC webcam stream to android lag

Tags: android, stream, video-streaming, webcam, vlc

I'm trying to stream my webcam live to an android VideoView over my local network. The video shows up but after a huge 15-20 seconds lag.
VLC streaming settings:
usgin HTTP
Enacpsulation: MPEG-TS
Video Codec: H-264
Resolution: 640 x 480
Bitrate: I keep changing it trying to figure out a suitable one.
VLC output string:

```
:sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=2000,fps=30,scale=1,width=640,height=480,acodec=none}:http{mux=ts,dst=:8080/stream} :sout-all :sout-keep
```

Android VideoView code:

```
VideoView view1 = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1); 
 getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

 MediaController mc = new MediaController(this); 
 mc.setMediaPlayer(view1); 

 view1.setMediaController(mc); 
 view1.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http://192.168.1.101:8554/stream")); 
 view1.requestFocus(); 
 view1.start();
```

I have searched everywhere for this problem but can't seem to find a solution, so any advice would be highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with VideoView, but why is your code referencing port 8554 when VLC is streaming on port 8080?

I recommend setting your [GOP size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_of_pictures) to [something around 120](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC-0-8-6_command-line_help)( `--sout-x264-min-keyint <integer>`), as a starting point for testing.

Comment: This post might help you get closer to where you're going...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762063/vlc-desktop-streaming?rq=1